# Why does included a call to fprintf prevent my program from getting a Segmentation fault?

Tags: c

Working on the "Two piles difference" community puzzle on Codingame.com. I got the program running and it passed all the tests, but it had a bunch of debug statements. When I turned them off, I got a Segmentation fault. I mucked around and got it down to one line:

```
fprintf(stderr, "list: %x" EOL, list);
```

Leave the line in and program runs fine. Comment it out and it crashes.
Same thing happens when I run the program on my Linux box.
Source file is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNrocOKYP7fb1dhQUpGZ2M0QzA/view?usp=sharing

```
/* Two piles difference
Given a list of N natural numbers, distribute the values into two lists A and B of size N/2,
so that the squared sum of A elements is the nearest possible to the product of the B
elements. 

Consider the list 7 11 1 9 10 3 5 13 9 12.
The optimized distribution is:
List A: 5 9 9 12 13
List B: 1 3 7 10 11
which leads to the difference abs( (5+9+9+12+13)^2 - (1*3*7*10*11) ) = 6
Your program should therefore output 6, which is the minimum difference that can be achieved.
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define EOL                 "\n"

// Build a sorted list of numbers and their count.

typedef struct
{
    int value;
    int count;
    int acount;     // for use in calculating the result.
}   item_t;

int     list_next   = 0;

int intcmp(const void* p1, const void* p2)    // used by qsort & bsearch
{
    return ((item_t*)p1)->value - ((item_t*)p2)->value;
}

void additem(item_t* list, int value)
{
    item_t* p        = &list[list_next];    // stick value in next empty slot
            p->value = value;
            p->count = 1;                   // now see if it is already in the list
            p        = (item_t*)bsearch(p, list, list_next,  sizeof(item_t), intcmp);

    if (p!=NULL)        // value is already in list
        p->count++;         
    else
    {                   // value is not in list, add it
        list_next++;
        qsort(list, list_next, sizeof(item_t), intcmp);
    }
}

// Do the required math

int N2;               // one half of the N, the number of numbers
int mind = INT_MAX;   // minimum difference

void compute(item_t* list)
{
//    fprintf(stderr, "list: %x" EOL, list);
//    printf("list: %x" EOL, list);

    int temp = list;

    int ax = 0;
    int bx = 0;
    int A[N2];
    int B[N2];

    for (int i=0; i<list_next; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (   ; j < list[i].acount; j++)
            A[ax++] = list[i].value;

        for (   ; j < list[i].count; j++)
            B[bx++] = list[i].value;
    }

    if (ax != bx)
        return;

    int As = 0;             // calculate the square of the sum of factors in the A list
    for (int j=0; j<N2; j++)
        As += A[j];
    As *= As;

    int Bp = 1;             // compute product of factors in B list
    for (int j=0; j<N2; j++)
        Bp *= B[j];

    int Diff = As - Bp;

    if (mind > abs(Diff))
        mind = abs(Diff);
}

// Generate all possible lists of factors

void permute(item_t* list, int level, int total)
{
    if (level   > list_next )   return;

    if (total   ==  N2      )
        compute(list);
    else
        for (int i=0; i<=list[level].count; i++)
        {
            list[level].acount = i;
            permute(list, level + 1, total + i);
        }
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    N2 = N / 2;
    item_t  list[N];
    memset(list, 0, sizeof(list));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        additem(list, x);
    }

    permute(list, 0, 0);

    printf("%d" EOL, mind);

    return 0;
}
```

Input file:

```
16
2 3 5 4 7 4 20 17 19 18 16 20 17 2 1 3
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. This is necessary not only to make verification and debugging of the problem as straightforward as possible for us, but also to preserve the validity of the question, once the problem is fixed. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Most likely your program is invoking undefined behavior, which means anything can happen (including the program seeming to run correctly under certain circumstances but crashing under slightly different ones for no obvious reason).  More helpfully, my guess would be that your program is writing to an invalid array index at some point and corrupting the stack in such a way that the corruption is detected/trapped when the fprintf() call is absent, but left untrapped when it is present.  I suggest running your program under valgrind, valgrind can give you a good hint about where the damage occurs

Comment: Also: `int temp = list;` Please what?

Comment: It is likely that you have an uninitialized local variable somewhere.  Because it's uninitialized, it receives a random initial value, depending on whatever bits and bytes were left behind on the stack by other functions that came before.  `fprintf` is a big and complicated function, so it leaves plenty of random bits and bytes behind on the stack that wouldn't otherwise have been there.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=list[level].count; i++)` is suspicious as `list[level]` maybe outside `list[]`.  IOWs, could `level >= N`?

Comment: As the other comments said, undefined behaviour. Any "explanation" is pure guesswork. So here is a guessplanation, but don't you dare relying on this ever. `printf()` & Co in my experience allocate very large bufferr on the stack. Having them anywhere inside your program will get you a much larger stack than without. After bloating the stack this way, it is harder to access beyond it., So, whatever very horrible things you are doing, it might be hushed up to stay at least within your stack. That will probably hurt this program sooner or later, but it does not try to meddle elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I must be getting rusty. I thought for sure I had tripped over a bug in the compiler, but now I realize there are several things I haven't checked. I pulled up gdb and did a little poking around. Apparently parameters are no longer passed by pushing them on the stack, and if you only have a single parameter it gets passed in EAX register. Anyway, something wonky is going on, so this gives me a chance to refresh my debug skills.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are all right. I was overrunning a local array because I wasn't checking ax or bx after incrementing in function compute.